# how to disable or hide “get link to this cell” in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

when showing google sheet in iframe, is there a possible way to disable or hide "get link to this cell" in google sheets context menu (Right Click menu).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)'s display the content as-is and for security reasons you are not allowed to modify it.

If you are interested in creating a customised view of your Sheet, I suggest you consider using the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) and create your own view using web technologies.